# How to move columns of a dataframe to be multi-index headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

```
data = {'0':['Col1', 'Col1_1', 10,9,8],'1':['Col1', 'Col1_2', 10,9,8], '2':['Col2', 'Col1_1', 10,9,8],'2':['Col2', 'Col1_2', 10,9,8]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'd like to modify the code above to where the first 2 columns in the dataframe are multi-index columns? So moving "Col1" and "Col1_1" to be columns in a muli-index dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

See if this is what you are asking for :

```
df1.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.iloc[0:2].values)

#delete the first 2 rows because they are also the columns
df1=df1.iloc[2:]

df1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should “accept” the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  __This is not a forum. If you wish to thank somebody, you should [vote him up](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up).__ We require a little bit of [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) before you can do that to prevent abuse; why don't you get some by [answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered)?